# C++ programing code counts[s[i] - '0'] ++;

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
   if (isdigit(s[i]))
   counts[s[i] - '0'] ++;
}
```

what does this code means, any one can able to explain this code " counts[s[i] - '0'] ++;" exact opertion

Comment: Counting number of each digit `0-9` in an array.

Answer (score 5):

`counts` is a ten-element array, which is being used to count how many times each digit appears in `s`.

Specifically:

- `s[i] - '0'` turns `'0'` into `0`, `'1'` into `1` etc.
- `counts[...]++` increments the corresponding element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The code is counting how many times a digit `(1-9)` is appearing in string `s`.

Note. `'i' - '0'` is the same as `i - 0` if `i` is a `digit`. 
The reason is that characters `'0' -'9'` have consecutive ASCII values. So the difference in ASCII value between `'i'` and `'0'` is `i`;

Now let's say

```
string s = "1b21cc55";
```

and

```
int count[10] is all zeros
```

in the loop

we check `s[i]`,

```
s[0] = 1 ---> isdigit(1) = yes ----> count[1-0] += 1  ---> count[1] is 1;    
s[1] = b ---> isdigit(b) = no ;
s[2] = 2 ---> isdigit(2) = yes ----> count[2-0] += 1; ---> count[2] is 1;        
s[3] = 1 ---> isdigit(1) = yes ----> count[1-0] += 1; ---> count[1] is 2;
```

and so on ...

At the end `count[i]` will tell you how many `i`s are in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

1) Ascii value of '0' is 48

2) Whenever s[i] is a digit (between 0-9 inclusive)

3) s[i] - '0' evaluates to an index (between 0..9 inclusive);

Example: 
Ascii value of '1' is 49
Say s[i] is '1'
then s[i] - '0' is 49-48 = 1

4) counts[s[i]-'0']++  would count the number of times a particular digit has been found in s[i].

Comment: The beauty of `s[i] - '0'` is that it works even if the character coding is not ASCII. On my IBM mainframe the code for `'0'` is 240, but the code still works!

Comment: yeah that's right, the code is portable. I just picked Ascii chart as an example.

Answer (score 1):

- `counts` is an array.
- `s[i]` is a character which contains numbers in ASCII. `'0'`, `'1'`,
  `'2'`, ...
- `s[i] - '0'` converts them into integer numbers. `1`, `2`, `3`, ...
- Above number indicates the index of n'th item in the array --> `X`
- `counts[X] ++` increments one the X'th item of the array.